# Как установить vue-cli без ошибок?

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli

Устанавливаю vue cli командой "npm install -g @vue/cli". В консоле ошибки:

npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! errno EINTEGRITY
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel%2fhelper-module-imports: Integrity verification failed for sha512-FCoU8jYGYvDol8PuK8Lgos7B/EhWGrVSLM+O/mnmO1HcBk8aOTT1gEaG+Tax6IMm8G2bHjF0DZ0YP0kGmA4rSA== (C:\Users\Вадим\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_cacache\content-v2\sha512\14\2a\14f2360662f0e897c3ee2bc2e0a2cec1fc48561ab5522ccf8efe69e63b51dc064f1a3934f5804686f936b1e88326f06d9b1e31740d9d183f4906980e2b48)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Вадим\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-02-28T06_10_28_628Z-debug.log

Что с этим делать?

Answer (score 0):

есть три варианта (взято из issue на github по этой проблеме), возможно один из них вам поможет:

1. попробуйте почистить кэш npm, `npm cache clean --force` и повторить ваши действия по установке vue-cli
2. удалить `package-lock.json`
3. также можете попробовать `npm cache verify`